# Reddit PRAW - how to search for submissions with score > 10k?

Tags: python, api, reddit, praw

I trying to for most upvoted post in /r/all like this

```
subreddit.search('score:>=10000', sort='new', syntax='cloudsearch')
```

But it return all submissions with a score less than 10,000.
How to use the search() method to retrieve submissions with a score of at least 10000?